# How to add user in open fire using PHP?

Tags: php, curl, openfire

I'd like to create a user in open fire in PHP using curl, please help.

```
<?php

    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?
    <user>
    <username>nitin</username>
    <password>patel</password>
    </user>";
    $url = "http://111.111.111.111:5223/plugins/userService/users";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
    echo "\n<br />";
    $contents = '';
    }
    else {
    curl_close($ch);
    }
    if (!is_string($contents) || !strlen($contents)) {
    echo "Failed to get contents.";
    $contents = '';
    }
    echo $contents;
?>
```

it gives output:P

Comment: Aren't you going to burn the guy if you create him on open fire?

Comment: Hi @Jurik I am getting P in output it is very surprised output

Answer (score 2):

Check [this page](http://xmppchat.blogspot.in/) to see the code for the connection and also for adding the user on the server

Answer (score 1):

Go to openfire administration and install REST API Plugin then follow the API. It allows users ang groups CRUD.
You need to set the Secret key and Allowed IP Addresses in order to use the API

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the connection timeout from 5 to 30 then try again.

Comment: Still the output is same

Comment: Are you able to view the url in the browser.

Comment: Also check the end tag is not closed in the first line.

Comment: Hi I directly hit this URL with this code without using XML (myip/plugins/userService/…) it works fine on local host but on server it give result : couldn't connect to host Failed to get contents.